# TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable when I am not calling any functions to iterate on

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've seen this error plenty of other times when I've messed up calling my functions that return iterables, but this time I'm pretty stuck. To my knowledge I've followed the sytax here correctly. Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

What I've done so far:

- Verified that the column in question is formatted correctly and free of NaNs
- Validated the regex in an external tool
- Rewritten the statement

Here's the code that I am using to generate the regex and the filter my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = ['2019-01-01']
only_onboarding = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ClosedDate'])

cycle_times = pd.DataFrame;
today = datetime.today();
for i in range(today.month - 1):  # Regex Model: 2019-08-\d\d$
    regx = "";

    if (i + 1 < 10):
        regx = str(today.year) + '-0' + str(i + 1) + '-\d\d$';
    else:
        regx = str(today.year) + '-' + str(i + 1) + '-\d\d$';

of_month = only_onboarding['ClosedDate'].filter(lambda x: re.match(regx, x));
```

Comment: @ALollz, adding ,axis=1 to the filter call generates more errors

Comment: @Trenton_M This is already pretty slimmed down. The dataframe is irrelevent, its just a column with dates in the form of '2019-mm-dd'. I've already verified that the regex is fine with an external tool.

Comment: We're not asking you to slim it down. We're asking for something we can run, that reproduces the error when run. It should be as short as possible given those constraints, but runnability is important.

Comment: @user2357112 See update. Should give you the error.

Comment: @Trenton_M See update, my bad

Comment: Why are you using `filter`? You can't use a `lambda` with filter. Do you mean `.apply`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to filter such that you only keep elements that match some regex, use:

```
only_onboarding[only_onboarding['ClosedDate'].str.match(regx)]
```

First, `DataFrame#filter` wants (1) `items` which lists the indices to keep, (2) a function `like` which allows you to calculate what items you want to keep, and (3) a `regex` parameter which, if matching, retains the row. You're getting a type error because the function is expecting items.

Second, `DataFrame#filter` and `Series#filter` operate on the *labels* in the index and not on the values contained in them.

Comment: So does DataFrame#filter always return a series? I'm getting an empty one now that the error is resolved (which shouldn't be the case, it should contain the one element in only_onboarding. All the tools I've used to test the regex show that it should work.

Comment: (1) You're subsetting to series by using `only_onboarding['ClosedDate']`, which then invokes `Series#filter` which returns the series. (2) I made a mistake in reading the docs above and have updated the answer accordingly: both `DataFrame#filter` and `Series#filter` apply _only_ to the _labels_ in the _index_. If you want to filter based on content matches in a certain column, use the subsetting syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pandas dataframe.filter documentation: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

You're passing a lambda to the filter method like the python builtin function, but that's not what the panda's filter function expects. The first positional argument to it is expected to be a list, which is the source of the "function" object is not iterable error.